# CallBack Error updating graph.figure - DASH

Tags: callback, plotly-dash

New here and to the world of python.

Generating a histogram plot where it changes color when a postcode is selected.

Now I have the main histogram but when the postcode is selected from the dropdown it gives the error. Unable to figure out how to resolve this. I have provided my full code below.

Let me know if more info is required to figure out the error. Something to do with input

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output


app = Dash(__name__)
app.title = "EGMs in NSW"
# Load your data : br = .....

datalist=pd.read_excel('premises-list-Aug-2022.xlsx',skiprows=[0,1,2])
datalist['Licence type'] = datalist['Licence type'].str.split(" - ").str.get(1)
datalist['Licence type'] = datalist['Licence type'].str.title()

postcode = datalist['Postcode']
postcode = postcode.sort_values(ascending=True)
postcode=list(dict.fromkeys(postcode))
pd.Series(datalist['Postcode'].unique()).sort_values(ascending=True)

def make_histogram_plot():
    
    # Create scatter plot
    fig=px.histogram(
        data_frame = datalist,
        x='Licence type',y='EGMs',color='Postcode',title='EGMs by Licence Type in NSW',
        histfunc='avg'
    )
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(color="#002664"))
    fig.update_layout(
        plot_bgcolor='#EAEDF4',
        xaxis_title=None,
        yaxis_title='Average EGMs'
    )
    return fig

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(postcode,value=[], placeholder="Select postcodes", multi=True, id='postcodes')
    ]),
    
    dcc.Graph(id = 'graph',figure = make_histogram_plot())

])

@app.callback(
    Output('graph','figure'),
    Input('postcodes','value')

)

def dropdown_changed(postcodes):
    if postcodes==[]:
        fig = make_histogram_plot()
    else:

        datalist2 = datalist[datalist['Postcode'].isin(postcodes)],
    # Create scatter plot
        fig=px.histogram(
        data_frame = datalist2,
        x='Licence type',y='EGMs',color='Postcode',title='EGMs by Licence Type in NSW',
        histfunc='avg'
    )
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(color="#002664"))
    fig.update_layout(
        plot_bgcolor='#EAEDF4',
        xaxis_title=None,
        yaxis_title='Average EGMs'
    )
    return fig

# Start the server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your data to the question because I am unable to run your program without the CSV file.

Comment: Hi Hamzah, not sure why but it won't let me attach the file. how do add the sample data?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your email ID so I can send it to you via email?

Comment: Add it to your git and share the link.

Comment: I like it already. Bud, I am 3 months old in this world of data analysis so not so savvy...yet!!! I am hearing about GitHub but have not used it yet. I will see what I can do.

Comment: It is simple, read this to upload any file to Github: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/adding-a-file-to-a-repository#:~:text=On%20GitHub.com%2C%20navigate%20to,repository%20onto%20the%20file%20tree.

Comment: What is the full traceback of the error?